# Grouping SpriteKit nodes, and zPosition controll

Tags: swift, swift4

I am using SpriteKit.
For character with parts of multiple SKSpriteNode, I'd like to controll overlap of nodes for each character.

For example, the character consists of notes and order of parts as follows.
Since `addChild` is done in order from the top, the head is displayed at the top in the appearance (it is forced by zPosition because occasionally collapses)

```
Body (z = 100)
    Leg (z = +1)
    Hand (z = +2)
    Head (z = +3)
```

If it overlaps with other characters, we will treat it so that there is a depth on the 2D screen below.

```
HumanA.zPosition = -humanA.position.y
HumanB.zPosition = -humanB.position.y
```

In the case of `humanA.position.y=-101`, `humanB.position.y=-100`, humanB is before humanA. But humanA's head (z = -98) is before humanB's leg (z = -99).

Ideally, if humanB is in front of humanA, I would like to make all parts of humanB ahead of humanA.

Please help me.

Reference site
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/sknode

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply multiply the y position by the number of human parts: 4

```
HumanA.zPosition = -humanA.position.y * 4
HumanB.zPosition = -humanB.position.y * 4
```

This way:

- human bodies may have the following z positions: 0, 4, 8, 12, 16, ...
- human legs may have the following z positions: 1, 5, 9, 13, 17, ...
- human hands may have the following z positions: 2, 6, 10, 14, 18, ...
- human heads may have the following z positions: 3, 7, 11, 15, 19, ...

Therefore, the whole parts of a single human will always be displayed at the same depth.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed explanation.